# Can I use thrust::host_vector or I must use cudaHostAlloc for zero-copy with Thrust?

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust, zero-copy

I want to use zero-copy on mapped memory by `cudaHostGetDevicePointer`. Can I use `thrust::host_vector` or I must use `cudaHostAlloc(...,cudaHostAllocMapped)?`
Or is it somehow easier to do with Thrust?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure it still isn't possible to  use a thrust::host_vector as a mapped host allocation. There is a pinned memory allocator, but I don't believe mapped memory is available. What you need to do is something like this:

1. Allocated mapped, pinned host memory with `cudaHostAlloc`
2. Get the device pointer for the zero copy memory using `cudaHostGetDevicePointer`
3. Create a `thrust::device_ptr` using `thrust::device_pointer_cast` on that device pointer (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/source/browse/examples/cuda/wrap_pointer.cu) for more information)

You can the either make a `thrust::device_vector` using the `thrust::device_ptr` or dirctly pass the `thrust::device_ptr` to any algorithms which accept an iterator.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I make thrust::device_vector using the thrust::device_ptr?

Comment: You can create a `thrust::device_vector` from an iterator range, so something like `thrust::device_vector<int> v(p, p+n)` creates vector `v` from the `device_ptr` `p` which points to an allocation of `n` elements.

Comment: But it will be create new device_vector and copy memory from device_ptr p to vector, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it creates a new `device_vector`, but no, it won't allocate any memory or do any copying. The instance will refer to the zero copy memory you allocated.

Comment: Thrust [fallback allocator example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/cuda/fallback_allocator.cu) gives a possible implementation along the lines of what talonmies describes, to implement mapped pinned memory with thrust.